# How can I make sure that when I write in the wolfram language, I'm writing exactly what I intend (or what others are writing)?

Tags: series-expansion

I'm someone who is just starting to do some hobbyist math on my own, using various tools like wolfram alpha, and I have a question about the wolfram command line. My question is as follows

[image]

I'm not very good with the wolfram language (really not), so I've tried a lot of different things I can do, but I'm not sure how to write a command to output something like the image above. I was wondering if you could give me some advice on this?

Comment: `results = Sum[(-1)^j/j! x^j,{j,0,\[Infinity]}]Table[Sum[k^n/k! x^k,{k,0,\[Infinity]}],{n,1,10}]` and then `Simplify[results]`?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.